# phpmyadmin composer says openssl and iconv are not installed

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, macports

I had a working install of phpmyadmin, but after reinstalling php via MacPorts (long story) I am getting the following message:

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies
> require the following PHP extensions to be installed: iconv, openssl

php -m tells me that openssl is installed and the comments in the php.ini file say iconv is depreciated.

What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

I am running Apache 2.4.49 with mySQL 8.0.12. I get the same error running php 8.0 and 7.4. MacOS 10.13 (trying to make good use of an old machine as a server) phpmyadmin is in /opt/local/www/apache2/html.

PHP is being parsed properly and MySQL is serving data as expected from various php scripts.

Comment: Do you have a different `php.ini` file for CLI and the web server, sounds like it

Comment: create a page containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?> and check the locations of the `php.ini` being read

Comment: The loaded php.ini is as expected /opt/local/etc/php74/php.ini, the same I created from php.ini-development.